# Where to set host name for dev/staging/production in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, standards

My Rails (3.2.21) app sends a lot of email, and it's frequently tested in dev and staging environments. As a result, whenever there's a URL in the email body, the host name needs to match the environment. Example:

- Dev: http://localhost:3000/something
- Staging: http://example.staging.com/something
- Production: http://example.com/something

Currently, I have an initializer in `initializers/setup_email.rb` that sets the `ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host]` variable depending on the environment (this initializer also sets up other email settings fwiw). **Staging** for instance is `ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "example.staging.com"`.

The **dev** conditional block however has a `:host` **AND** `:port`, so it looks like this:

```
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost"
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:port] = 3000
```

In my mailer classes, I have these ugly conditionals everywhere there's a URL to display, since I need to account for port in dev. Like this:

```
if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.staging?
    @url = "http://#{ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host]}/something"
elsif Rails.env.development?
    @url = "http://#{ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host]}:#{ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:port]}/something"
end
```

What best practice am I missing here? Should I just have the above conditional statement *once* atop my mailer class before any methods, so I set a `@host` variable once and forget it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to define a custom constant in `development.rb`, `production.rb`, and `staging.rb`.

Something like:

```
# development.rb
mailer_host = ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost"
mailer_port = ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:port] = 3000
MailerURL = "http://#{mailer_host}:#{mailer_port}"

# production.rb
mailer_host = ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "foo.com"
MailerURL = "http://#{mailer_host}"
```

That way you can avoid the conditionals. Just use `MailerURL` and it will be different depending on the environment

Answer (score 0):

You can also save it as an environment variable `ENV["HOST_URL"]`